proving a function is Lebesgue integrable

Let $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \ln n, & \text{if }
 \dfrac{1}{n+1} < x \leq \dfrac{1}{n}, \\ 0, & \text{if } x = 0.
\end{cases} $$ Prove that $f$ is not Riemann integrable but is
Lebesgue integrable on $[0, 1]$ and compute $\int_{0}^{1} f \, d\mu$.

$\ln n =0\iff n=1\iff x\in(\dfrac{1}{2},1]$. So the set of discontinous points of $f$ in $[0,1]$ is $[0,\dfrac{1}{2}]$ has measure $\dfrac{1}{2}\neq 0$. Hence $f$ is not Riemann integrable.
I don't know how to prove $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0, 1]$. May be we can use Monotone Convergence Theorem or Dominated Convergence Theorem?
Any help I would be much grateful

Why have you equated "points of discontinuity" with "function is nonzero"?  That's not what that means at all.  Rather, think about what $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$ is and how that impacts whether $f$ is Riemann-integrable.

Hint: $|f(x)| =2 \ln \sqrt n \le 2\sqrt n$ for $\frac1 {n+1}<x\le \frac 1 n$.

@geetha290krm I don't get your hint

If $\ln (\frac  1n)$ is replaced by $2\sqrt n$ in the definition of $f$, would the new function be integrable? If, so you are done.

@geetha290krm could you write your solution in the answering section down below so that I can understand better?

You have  a poor record of voting for answers, so I won't.

So sorry everyone, I edited the problem. It is $\ln n$, not $\ln\dfrac{1}{n}$.

There is no difference between $\ln (\frac 1n)$ and $\ln n$ because $f$ is Lebesgue  integrable iff $|f|$ is. $|\ln (\frac 1n)|$ is same as $|\ln n|$.

@geetha290krm the value of the function changes depending on $n$. I don't know $|f(x)|\leq 2\sqrt{n}$ for $\frac{1}{n+1}<x\leq\frac{1}{n}$ got to do if it isn't fixed for every $x$.

It is not Riemann integrable because it is unbounded. The set of discontinuities has measure zero.

Let $g(x)=2\sqrt n$ for $\frac  1{n+1} <x \le \frac  1n$, $n=1,2,...$ and $g(0)=0$. Verify that $|f(x)|\le |g(x)$ for all $x$. If we show that $g$ is integrable then we can conclude that $f$ is integrable. Now compure $\int |g(x)|dx$ directly. You get $\sum_n 2\sqrt n (\frac  1n -\frac 1{n+1})=\sum_n \frac 2 {\sqrt n (n+1)}<\sum_n \frac 2 {(\sqrt n) n}<\infty$.

could I ask why $g$ is integrable?

It is a measurable function and $\int |g(x)|dx<\infty$.

Thank you! I understand now

The integral is
$$
\sum_n\log n\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=\sum_n\frac{\log n}{n(n+1)}
$$
which is finite (e.g. $\log x=O(x^{\epsilon})$ as $x\to\infty$ for any $\epsilon>0$).
The function isn't Riemann integrable because it is unbounded (the set of discontinuities is countable, hence measure zero).

Sorry, I mistyped the problem. It is $\ln n$, not $\ln\dfrac{1}{n}$.
